# How to make promises in ES6 work in IE10, IE11 and Safari?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, safari, internet-explorer-11, es6-promise

I have an ECMAScript 6 code that runs on all browsers except Internet Explorer (including 10 and 11) and Safari. How can I make it work on all browsers?

I have tried to convert the code from ES6 to ES5 using https://babeljs.io/
but it gives me the same code.

```
// override show method of Modal.js
(function ModalController() {
   var show = Modal.prototype.show;
    Modal.prototype.show = function() {
      // translate the settings buttons
      var promises = [];
      var that = this;
      this.settings.buttons.forEach(element => {

      var promise = Globalize.translate(element.label);
            promises.push(promise);
            promise.then(function(data) {
            element.label = data;
        });
    });
    // when all components are translated
       Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
        show.apply(that, []);
      })
  }

})();
```

Comment: If you tried to convert ES6 to ES5 with babel and "it give me the same code", simply put, you did it wrong.

Comment: Which just glancing at this code snippet, the main issue I see in regard to IE# would be the one arrow function.

Comment: @Taplar - Promise object is not supported in IE

Comment: So there's (at least) two things.  I wasn't saying the arrow function was the only issue.  Just the first one that jumped out at me.

Comment: The quickest way to solve this problem (and easiest if you are allowed) is to use the Polyfill for Promises and replace the arrow function with a traditional function expression. The Polyfill can be found here: https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise

Comment: Use a [polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill) This one works with IE8+